# ALL SSRS Report Parameter in Embedded SQL Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I am designing a SSRS Report with a single selection dropdown and embedded SQL. I would like to implement the `Select All` parameter.

Any suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, add parameter values for *all* variables. The other option would be to use a `defaults` table.

[image: screenshot]

Then union the parameter(s) to the datasets for your other parameters. This way you'll get the *all* option in your parameter dropdowns.

```
;WITH
teams_source
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 2323304)
    , ( 2323305)
    , ( 2323306)
    , ( 2323307)
    , ( 2323308)
    , ( 2323309)
    , ( 2323310)
    , ( 2323311)
    , ( 2323312)
    , ( 2323313)
    , ( 2323314)
    , ( 2323315)
    , ( 2323316)
    ) tbl ([Teams]) 
)
SELECT [Teams], [TeamsFormat] = CAST([Teams] AS VARCHAR) FROM teams_source
UNION
SELECT [Teams] = @all_value_nbr, [TeamsFormat] = @all_value_text
ORDER BY 1
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Then in the dataset for your report change the `WHERE` clause to check for the *all* variable.

```
WHERE 
1=1
AND (@all_value_nbr IN(@Teams) OR [Teams] IN(@Teams))
```

When you build the URL with parameters, you can count the number of values.

```
IIF(Parameters!Teams.Count = Count(Fields!Teams.Value, "TeamsDataset"), "", "@Teams=" + Join(Parameters!Teams.Value, "@Teams="))
```